# Why is my graph coloring code not coloring the graph correctly?

Tags: c++, graph-theory, graph-coloring

`solved`

I am solving a problem where we have to color a graph with 4 colors such that no adjacent nodes share same colors. I, firstly used a set based approach which wasn't working. Then I used a standard implementation which can be found at: https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-perform-greedy-coloring/

Here's my code but it is not working as intended:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
typedef long double ld;
#define int long long
#define pb push_back
#define all(x) x.begin(), x.end()

const int N = 105;
vector<int> graph[N];
vector<int> color(N);
bool unused[5];

signed main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        graph[x].pb(y);
        graph[y].pb(x);
    }
    color[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i<=n; i++){
        color[i] = -1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) unused[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        for(auto child: graph[i]){
            if(color[child] != -1) unused[color[child]] = 1;
        }
        int cr;
        for(cr = 1; cr <= 4; cr++){
            if(unused[cr]) break;
        }
        color[i] = cr;
        for(auto child: graph[i]){
            if(color[child] != -1) unused[color[child]] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) cout << color[i];
}
```

For this input:

```
5 6
4 1
4 2
4 3
2 5
1 2
1 5
```

I get the output `11511` but the correct output is `12133`.

Comment: There seem to be some clear differences between your code and the sample code (plus many obscure ones). For example the sample code subtracts one from all input vertices, but your code does not.

Comment: that difference doesn't matter. the sample is just using 0-based indexing but I want 1-based indexing. also the sample has colors starting from 0 but in my case they should be starting from 1

Comment: The sample is clearly using 1 based indexing, look at the diagram they've drawn.

Comment: its not about the drawing. their coloring is starting from 0 as well in the graph they are using 0 based indexing

Comment: `if(unused[cr]) break;` should be `if(unused[cr] == false) break;` or `if(!unused[cr]) break;`

Comment: thank you so much brother. I never realized this.

Comment: @WasifShahzad -- `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Why should I not include this header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). -- `#define int long long` -- What? Why are you doing this?  An `int` and `long long` are separate types. -- `#define pb push_back` -- Again, what's the reason for this macro?  A C++ programmer knows `push_back`, and by making it a macro, it just makes the code harder to read.  -- `signed main()` -- All because you messed up `int`.  Please do not use competitive coding websites to learn C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wish there were bounties for comments, there.

Comment: you write `pb` twice. That is 4 characters typing instead of 18 for `push_back` twice. To get there you had to type 20 characters. I ask you do to the maths to see how much typing you saved by using the macro. I made some rough general estimations here https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251154/114229. If its not for typing less or to make the code shorter I dont know what they are supposed to be good for. Such macros are simply not worth what you pay for them

Comment: If you are not by instinct typing in `#include <iostream>` and `#include <vector>` when you are using `std::cin` and `std::vector`, then you are not learning C++ properly.  The `bits` header shouldn't have even entered your thoughts.  Same thing with the `pb` macro -- if you are actually typing in that macro instead of just calling `push_back` where necessary, then you are not learning C++ properly.